# Traer un control de ascx a HTML

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Estoy cargando por AJAX, Jquery a través de un web service, un control dinámico .ascx, lo tengo todo montado pero el return no me capta el HTLM, solo me trae [objectXMLDocument]

```
`public class ShopingCart : System.Web.Services.WebService
{


    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod()]
    public string AddCart(int productId, int quantity)
    {
        ShoppingCartManager scm = new ShoppingCartManager(new DAL.ApplicationDbContext());
        var user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var sc = scm.GetAll().Where(e => e.User_Id == user && e.Product_Id == productId).SingleOrDefault();

        if (sc != null)
            sc.Quantity = sc.Quantity + quantity;
        else {
            ShoppingCart shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart
            {

                Product_Id = productId,
                User_Id = user,
                Quantity = quantity,
            };
            scm.Add(shoppingCart);
        }
        scm.Context.SaveChanges();
        return "hola";
    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: Que debe de retornar "hola"?

Comment: Es porque declaras la función como string, me falta información para ver que es lo que realmente quieres, pero si quieres que te retorne el objeto en string conviertelo a [JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: Hola Nicolas, el código lo tengo en mi git, te linkeo la página donde está el asmx que está el web service, y el ajax:https://github.com/byeveweb/EShopOs/blob/master/EShopOS.Web/Controls/ShopingCart.asmx.cs y el ajax es: https://github.com/byeveweb/EShopOs/blob/master/EShopOS.Web/Client/ProductsFiles/ProductCat.aspx